# Classify subrepresentations in finite dimensional semisimple representations

Tags: representation-theory

Quoted from "forgetfulfunctor":

> I'm following the notes by Prof. Etingof, linked [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Eetingof/replect.pdf), and am stuck on a detail from Prop. 2.2, on page 23.
>
> To briefly recap what is in the notes, we have a finite dimensional, semisimple representation $V=\oplus_i n_iV_i$ of an algebra $A$, where $\{V_i\}$ are pairwise nonisomorphic. We wish to show that any subrepresentation $W\subset V$ is of the form $\oplus_i r_iV_i$ for $r_i\le n_i$.

I'm following Etingof's proof but have some trouble from the following: ……and upon identification of $P$ with $V_i$ is given by the formula $v\rightarrow (vq_{1},\dots,vq_n) $, where $q_l \in k$ are not all zero.
Why could it be written in this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in Remark 2.3 below this proposition, this is only true if $k$ is algebraically closed. In that case, it follows from Schur's lemma for algebraically closed fields, that is Corollary 1.17.

More precisely, identifying $P$ with $V_i$, you are given a map in $\operatorname{Hom}(V_i,n_iV_i)\cong n_i\operatorname{Hom}(V_i,V_i)$. By Corollary 1.17, $\operatorname{Hom}(V_i,V_i)$ is given by scalar multiplication with some $q\in k$. Thus, $\operatorname{Hom}(V_i,n_iV_i)$ is in each component given by multiplication with some scalar $q_i\in k$. Since the map $P\to n_iV_i$ is injective, as it is just a submodule inclusion, in particular it is non-zero and so, one of the scalars $q_i$ has to be non-zero.

Comment: Thank you! I' stuck in the direct sum of copies of $V_i$ , which turns out to be meaningless. In my head , I have to choose different $v$s(these $v$s lie in different copies of $V_i$). Actually I've learned some elementary representation theory of groups and algebras, somehow Etingof's book seems a little strange for me. The time when I saw the isomorphism of Hom functor and direct sum , I knew where I misunderstood.